# Notification persistence across pages with Laravel, Redis & Socket.io

Tags: laravel-5, redis, socket.io

I am working on Laravel 5.3 , Redis and Socket.io. I am able to successfully get the notification on client side with Laravel broadcasting.
But when a page is refreshed, all notifications are lost.
Is there a way to persist these notification across various pages ?

Comment: You could save them as a cookie or in the `localStorage` object or with the Filesystem API https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: You could also use laravel's database notifications alongside with broadcasting. This way you can notify & display new notifications without reloading the page. After a reload happens the database notifications will still be there. [Database Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#database-notifications)

Comment: Will try with database notifications @MoritzEwert

Comment: I have the same issue, may be you consider read the state from a centalized repository on the server side.